# set cache in QtWebKit

Tags: qt, browser-cache, cache-control, qtwebkit

So I wrote this class overriding the base QWebPage.

This is with Qt4.8.5. I cannot really upgrade to a more recent version for all kind of reasons... Anyway the caching classes have been introduced in 4.4 so I should be fine.

This is written based on the following doc: https://web.archive.org/web/20140129011151/http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2011/04/29/http-caching-with-qt/

```
MyQWebPage::MyQWebPage(QObject* parent /*= nullptr*/) : QWebPage(parent)
{
    QWebHistory *history = this->history();
    history->setMaximumItemCount(0);

    QNetworkAccessManager * pNAM = networkAccessManager();
    if (pNAM) {
        QNetworkDiskCache * pNDC = new QNetworkDiskCache(parent);
        pNDC->setCacheDirectory( QDir::homePath() + "/AppData/Roaming/Autodesk/ash_web_cache" );

        qint64 size = pNDC->cacheSize();
        printf( "cache size = %ld\n", size );

        size = pNDC->maximumCacheSize();
        printf( "maximum cache size = %ld\n", size );

        const qint64 desired = 1024*1024*1024;

        if (size < desired) {
            pNDC->setMaximumCacheSize(desired);
            size = pNDC->maximumCacheSize();
            printf( "new maximum cache size = %ld\n", size );
        }

        QString dir = pNDC->cacheDirectory();
        printf( "cache directory = %s\n", (const char*)dir.toUtf8() );

        pNAM->setCache(pNDC);
    }
}
```

I am giving 1GB of cache for now just to make sure that what I'm doing should be cached properly.

So I have my webapp showing up, I open the inspector, I go in the network tab.
My web page shows a bunch of thumbnail images.
When I reload my page I dont see much caching taking place although there should be plenty of space available !

If I do the same thing in chrome all my thumbnails get a 200-OK-fromcache, as expected!
So there is no problem with the date, etag etc since it's all working in chrome.

But in this qt web app, no, not even a 304...  Everything is a 200 no cache at all.

The printf lines in the code above will print:

```
cache size = 8342691

maximum cache size = 52428800

new maximum cache size = 1073741824
```

The cache size of 8342691 is exactly the size of the directory I had set in `setCacheDirectory` (precisely, one of its subdirectories called data7)...
But I cant find my thumbnails in there.

Is there anything I am doing wrong?

BTW I noticed this function here in QtWebSettings:

```
void QWebSettings::setObjectCacheCapacities(int cacheMinDeadCapacity, int cacheMaxDead, int totalCapacity) [static]
```

I haven't tested this yet...

There is also this cache control that I could tweak:

```
enum QNetworkRequest::CacheLoadControl
Controls the caching mechanism of QNetworkAccessManager.
QNetworkRequest::AlwaysNetwork  0   always load from network and do not check if the cache has a valid entry (similar to the "Reload" feature in browsers); in addition, force intermediate caches to re-validate.
QNetworkRequest::PreferNetwork  1   default value; load from the network if the cached entry is older than the network entry. This will never return stale data from the cache, but revalidate resources that have become stale.
QNetworkRequest::PreferCache    2   load from cache if available, otherwise load from network. Note that this can return possibly stale (but not expired) items from cache.
QNetworkRequest::AlwaysCache    3   only load from cache, indicating error if the item was not cached (i.e., off-line mode)
```

But the default `AlwaysNetwork` should be fine so I don't think I need to change this.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same problem. It is a bug of document but not code logic.

Please add this line into your code.  setNetworkAccessManager(pNAM);

```
MyQWebPage::MyQWebPage(QObject* parent /*= nullptr*/) : QWebPage(parent)
{
QWebHistory *history = this->history();
history->setMaximumItemCount(0);

QNetworkAccessManager * pNAM = networkAccessManager();
if (pNAM) {
    setNetworkAccessManager(pNAM);
    QNetworkDiskCache * pNDC = new QNetworkDiskCache(parent);
    pNDC->setCacheDirectory( QDir::homePath() + "/AppData/Roaming/Autodesk/ash_web_cache" );

    qint64 size = pNDC->cacheSize();
    printf( "cache size = %ld\n", size );

    size = pNDC->maximumCacheSize();
    printf( "maximum cache size = %ld\n", size );

    const qint64 desired = 1024*1024*1024;

    if (size < desired) {
        pNDC->setMaximumCacheSize(desired);
        size = pNDC->maximumCacheSize();
        printf( "new maximum cache size = %ld\n", size );
    }

    QString dir = pNDC->cacheDirectory();
    printf( "cache directory = %s\n", (const char*)dir.toUtf8() );

    pNAM->setCache(pNDC);
}
```

}

It works for me.